# Post Fisher's exact test- how to weight within categorial differences?

Tags: weighted-sampling, fishers-exact-test

I am desperately looking for some statistical help with my data because I myself cannot transfer the theoretical stuff I lately read on residuals, chi square distributions, squared z-values ecetera to my problem. Therefore I would really appreciate somebody to help me on that:

I compared 2 distributions with 4 categories by using Fisher's exact test- the difference turned out to be significant.

Now I wanted to know which category is "responsible" for the difference. More specifically, I was interested in which of the 4 categories the observed values differed from the expected.

Therefore I calculated "standardized residuals" or "squared z-values" (if that is correct??), like this: (observed - expected) squared/ expected

category:     1; 2; 3;4

observed:     4;       7;       5;       56

expected:     1.4;      3.2;     4.6;     62.8

z-squared:    4.8;      4.5;     0.03;    0.73

Hence, from what I understand of this example the observed and expected values in category 3 and 4 are not "that" different, but well in category 1 and 2; But now what do the numbers exactly mean? Do they convey any information of contingency considering that the comparison deals with numbers of people in each category?

I would be very happy about any advice.
Kind regards,
Johanna

Comment: If you understand what a z-score is, you'd probably find Pearson residuals more interpretable, even though they tell you about contribution to chi-square rather than to the Fisher test - they'd still give you some sense. However the results you present here make no sense to me. If you have two groups of numbers on 4 categories, there should be 8 observed and 8 expected.

Comment: Sorry this is a misunderstanding: I did not present both distributions but one and in the second row the derived expected values under consideration of the other one. Now I want to know the exact (?) difference of my observed to the expected values. Is that more clear?

Comment: If that does help, the observed values of the second distribution were: 47; 109; 158; 2186

Answer (score 2):

Here are the (signed) square roots of the individual cell contributions to chi-square, essentially Pearson residuals for a Poisson model. They're not *actually* z-scores (they're on average a bit smaller - your $z^2$'s are probably actual squares of z scores).

```
> (a$observed-a$expected)/sqrt(a$expected)
             x1          x2
[1,]  2.1528248 -0.36534648
[2,]  2.0825076 -0.35341325
[3,]  0.2045836 -0.03471899
[4,] -0.8535520  0.14485258
```

We see - exactly as you suggested - the first two categories in the first variable seem to be what's "causing" significance.  Those values are slightly "unusually" large, while none of the others are.

Comment: Ok, but then, is there no way I can attribute a more specific meaning to a Pearson resiudal of 2 cpmpared to for instance a residual of 53 (maybe that's a stupid question, but this is what I am looking for)?

Comment: The interpretation is very similar to interpreting a z-score, as I already mentioned.

Comment: this is what i understand of z-values: it is a standardization, a space transformation under which each z-value has a specific probability. z has a mean of 0, z has a standard deviation of 1.

Comment: So you should be able to interpret your $z^2$ values; if you take square roots and attach the signs of the Poisson-type Pearson residuals you should have something you can interpret even more directly.

Comment: is this correct: frequency of category 1 in the x1 distribution is 2 standard deviations higher than expected?

Comment: Yes, approximately 2 sd's; that's also true of category 2 there.

Comment: Is the number of possible sd's under the z-distribution endless? and if I used Pearson residuals, what is their mean and SD?

Comment: "*Is the number of possible sd's under the z-distribution endless?*" - yes, but they become increasingly unlikely if the null hypothesis is true; the probability of being more than two standard deviations away from the mean is roughly 5%. The mean of the residuals that I gave is zero under the null. The standard deviation is a bit less than 1.

Comment: read about Pearson residuals Poisson model as you suggested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression; in my example do I calculate them like it says in your equation: observed - expected / squareroot (expected)? And how would you interpret the result of your calculation (considering we are talking about the numbers of persons)? e.g. in category 1 and 2 of x1 frequency= 2 standard deviations higher than expected?